# nuget package manager does not offer older versions of package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I inherited some old legacy code which I'm trying to build, but I'm missing some specific dlls. In particular, I need version 4.0.0.0 of `System.ComponentModel.Composition`, but the Nuget Package Manager options only go down to 4.5.0. Why is this, and how can I get the version I need?

Here is the line specified by the Web.config file I inherited.

```
<add assembly="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
```

[image]

__

Edit: I tried Jingmiao Xu-MSFT's solution but I'm getting an error saying I'm already referencing these packages. Then I noticed that I'd commented out these assembly lines in my Web.config, so where are these packages being referenced from?

[image]

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I could not resolve the issue because I could not find a way to check whether a package had been correctly added. As of now, I’ve abandoned the legacy project. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can refer to the following steps to find the dlls you need:

1. Right-click on the References under your project in Solution Explorer.
2. Choose Assemblies and search System.ComponentModel.Composition, System.Net.Http.WebRequest
   [image]
   [image]
3. Check them and add them to the project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was able to find the assemblies this way, but ran into another issue. I've edited my post, could you take a look?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Check the References, if System.Net.Heep.WebRequest already exists there is no need to add it. You can check if there is this dll file in the bin folder. You can also see the path by holding the mouse over it.